# Magento: Trigger a call on recurring (checkout)

Tags: php, api, magento

I'm looking for a link or tutorial on how to trigger a http call or function/method/class each time a recurring/sale/checkout is made in Magento..

I need to book all sales in an external accounting service

Have looked at this link, but it doesn't look like it can trigger on events in Magento?! Here you need to make the calls external
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api

Really hope someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0):

In every event, **magento** has been add a `dispatchEvent`.

like `sales_order_save_after/sales_order_delete_after/customer_customer_save_after` or many more. check the `$_eventPrefix` on a class. if there is `$_eventPrefix` on a class then you can call the Mage::DispatchEvent for trigger a call.

[MagentoCommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3459/)

[Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/)

Comment: In which folder do I put my module file so I don't need to monkey with the existing files/code

Comment: you must rewrite a module for that. http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/

Comment: I have never worked with magento before.. Could you please be more specific on which model or block I need to override? :)